# When I try to access to array items I only get the 1. one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Here's my Query

```
$rows = $mydb->get_results("SELECT title, description  
FROM site_info
WHERE site_id='$id';");
```

I get something like:

```
Title1 Desc1
Title2 Desc2
etc.
```

I want to put that data in array so I do:

```
    $data = array();
foreach ($rows as $obj) {
        $data['title'] = $obj->title;
        $data['description'] = $obj->description;
}
```

When I do:

```
print_r($data);
```

I only get title and description of first item... Please help :/ I checked and my query returns all what i want to be in array not only the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-writing array indexes each time in iteration.You need to create new indexes each time when you are assigning the values to array.

So either do:-

```
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $key=>$obj) { // either use coming rows index
   $data[$key]['title'] = $obj->title;
   $data[$key]['description'] = $obj->description;
}
```

Or

```
$data = array();
$i=0; //create your own counter for indexing
foreach ($rows as $key=>$obj) {
   $data[$i]['title'] = $obj->title;
   $data[$i]['description'] = $obj->description;
   $i++;// increase the counter each time after assignment to create new index
}
```

For display again use `foreach()`

```
foreach ($data as $dat) {
   echo $dat['title'];
   echo $dat['description'];
}
```

Comment: Thnk you. And how to display that now with echo for example? `title1 desc 1 $nbsp title2 desc2`

Comment: use `foreach()` for that too.

Answer (score 0):

If the eventual goal is simply to display these values, then you shouldn't bother with re-storing the data as a new multi-dimensional array.

```
$rows = $mydb->get_results("SELECT title, description FROM site_info WHERE site_id='$id';");
```

If `$id` is user-supplied data or from an otherwise untrusted source, you should implement some form of sanitizing/checking as a matter of security.  At a minimum, if the `$id` is expected to be an integer, cast it as an integer (an integer doesn't need to be quote-wrapped).

```
$rows = $mydb->get_results("SELECT title, description FROM site_info WHERE site_id = " . (int)$id);
```

When you want to display the object-type data, just loop through `$rows` and using `->` syntax to echo the values.

```
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($rows as $obj) {
        echo '<li>' , $obj->title , ' & ' , $obj->description , '</li>';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

---

If you have a compelling reason to keep a redundant / restructured copy of the resultset, then you can more simply command php to generate indexes for you.

```
foreach ($rows as $obj) {
    $data[] = ['title' => $obj->title, 'id' => $obj->id];
}
```

The `[]` is just like calling `array_push()`.  PHP will automatically assign numeric keys while pushing the associative array as a new subarray of `$data`.